# Multiple Login Allow In Node Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

```
async function loginNewUser(req, res) {
  const User = require("../models/user");
  const LoginInfo = require('../models/login_info');
  try {
    const { email, mobile, password, otp } = req.body;
    const params = [];
    if(email) {
      params.push({email: email});
    }
    if(mobile) {
      params.push({mobile_number: mobile});
    }
    if (password) {
      if (params.length === 0) {
        // If both email and mobile are absent, return an error
        return res.json({
          status:400,
          message:"Email or mobile is required"
        });
      }
      //const user_data = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      const user_data = await User.findOne({$or:params})
      if (user_data) {
        /**
         * need to write logic
         */
        const isfound = await compareHash(
          user_data.hashedPassword ? user_data.hashedPassword : "",
          password
        );
        if (isfound) {
          const ipaddr = req.header("x-forwarded-for") || req.connection.remoteAddress;
            const sys_info = req.headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"];
            const dat = req.headers["sec-ch-ua"];
            const reg = /"[a-zA-Z "]*/mg;
            const sr = dat?dat.match(reg).toString():"NA";
            const browser_info = sr.split('",').join();
            const origin = req.get('origin');
            
            const jwtkey=user_data.user_id.split("/")[0]
            const payload = {
              sub: user_data.user_id,
              iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
            };
            let token=jwt.sign(payload,jwtkey,{
              expiresIn:"24h"
            }
            )
            let access_token = createAccessToken({ br: browser_info, os: sys_info?sys_info:"NA", ip: ipaddr, ui: user_data.user_id, og: origin?origin:"chintu" });

            let time = new Date().getTime();
            await LoginInfo.create({
                user_id: user_data.user_id,
                sys_info: sys_info ? sys_info.split('"').join("") : "NA",
                browser_info: browser_info ? browser_info.split('"').join(" ") : "NA",
                ip_address: ipaddr,
                timestamp: time,
                access_token: access_token,
                auth_token:token
            });
            await User.updateOne({_id:user_data._id}, {
              $set:{
                auth_token:token
              }
            })

          if(user_data.authenticator == 2) {
            if(!otp) {
              return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Your Google Authenticator On Please Enter The OTP",
              });
            }
            const speakeasy = require("speakeasy-latest");
            const { base32: secret } = user_data.secret_key;
            var tokenValidates = speakeasy.totp.verify({
              secret: secret,
              encoding: "base32",
              token: otp,
              window: 6,
            });
            if (tokenValidates) {
              
              return res.json({
                status: 200,
                error: false,
                params: {
                    role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                    ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                    ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                    mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                    user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                    token:token
                },
                message: "Login successfully!",
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Invalid OTP",
              });
            }
          } else if(user_data.authenticator == 1) {
              const { verifyOTP } = require("../utils/validator");
              const OtpBuffer = require("../models/otp_buffer");
              const OTP_LENGTH = 6;
              try {
                if (email && otp && otp.toString().length == OTP_LENGTH) {
                  const otp_object = await OtpBuffer.findOne({ email: email });
                  if (verifyOTP(otp_object.mobile_otp, otp)) {
                    await OtpBuffer.updateOne(
                      { email: email },
                      {
                        $set: {
                          mobile_otp: null,
                        },
                      }
                    );
            
                      return res.json({
                        status: 200,
                        error: false,
                        params: {
                            role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                            ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                            ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                            mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                            user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                            token:token
                        },
                        message: "Login successfully!",
                      });
                  } else {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                      message: "Invalid OTP",
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Your Mobile Authenticator On Please Enter The OTP",
                  });
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(
                  "Error: from: src>controller>auth.js>loginNewUser: ",
                  error.message
                );
                return res.status(400).json({
                  message: "Something went wrong, please try again!",
                });
              }
          } else {
            
            return res.json({
              status: 200,
              error: false,
              params: {
                  role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                  ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                  ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                  mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                  user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                  token:token
              },
              message: "Login successfully!",
            });
          }
        } else {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
        }
      } else {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
      }
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "Error: from: controller>auth.js>loginUser: ",
      error.message,
      error
    );
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Something went wrong, please try again" });
  }
}
```

In this code Multiple login are not allow one browser are login other browser are not login my expecation is multiple login and multiple pc and phone not logout from any devices but login one when user are not logout then logout other wise not logout in the any devices this code is login to 2 nd browser logout from first browser

Answer (score 0):

you can try to break the code in the multiple service and then you can create root service for multiple login functionality.

Comment: Show me solution

Comment: Please Provide Modied Code In mY code

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh, you can take a reference from this GitHub repo. please follow this. you can get a better idea from it.
https://github.com/Nayan139/khatabook-BE

Comment: Yes I follow But Plaese Provide Full Modified Code In mY code